# golang MySQL segfaulting once abstracted

Tags: mysql, go

Basically, I'm trying to make an abstraction of the sql.db struct in order to write my own functions for it. However, when I try to do it it keeps segfaulting and I'm not sure why. Essentially, I have an abstraction of sql.db called ExtendedDB which is a struct that contains an sql.db. I do this in order to write my own functions that act on the ExtendedDB struct. The handling of that occurs in mysqlhandler.go I'm relatively new to lower level programming so I assume it has something to do with improper handling of pointers. Any help is appreciated!

Edit: It's panicking on line 25 when I call rows.Columns() to verify that the query went through. Weirdly enough, however, when debugging it recognizes rows as type *sql.rows which is correct. Furthermore, I know it's not erroring as if I do an `err != nil` check it passes.

main.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/blackcoffee77/tuilight/dbhandlers"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error loading .env file")
    }
    conn := os.Getenv("DATABASE_CONN")
    edb := dbhandlers.DBInit(conn)
    fmt.Println("here2")
    fmt.Printf("%T", edb.DB)
    rows, _ := edb.DB.Query("select * from people where id = ?", 1)

    fmt.Println(rows.Columns())
    edb.GetAll()
    fmt.Println("here6")

}
```

mysqlhandler.go

```golang
package dbhandlers

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type ExtendedDB struct {
    DB   *sql.DB
    Conn string
}

func (edb *ExtendedDB) getTables() *sql.Rows {
    fmt.Println("here5")
    res, _ := edb.DB.Query("select * from people where id = ?", 1)
    fmt.Println("here4")
    fmt.Println(res)
    return res
}

func (edb *ExtendedDB) GetAll() {
    tables := edb.getTables()
    fmt.Println("here3")
    fmt.Println(tables)
    // fmt.Println(tables.Columns())

}

func DBInit(conn string) *ExtendedDB {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", conn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    fmt.Println("got here")

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    edb := ExtendedDB{DB: db, Conn: conn}
    return &edb
}
```

Comment: Which line of code paniced?

Comment: Line 25, I edited the post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it panicking, or segfaulting? Those are very different. Please show the actual error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

"[defer](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12) db.Close()" is disconnecting from the database when the `DBinit` function exits

Comment: Wow I completely overlooked that. I thought it was way more complicated. One of those days I guess. Thanks for the help!